# Shortcut to create a javascript function stub in Sublime Text 2

Tags: javascript, textmate, stub, textmatebundles, sublimetext

Is it possible to quickly create a method stub in Sublime Text 2? Perhaps a package I could install?

For example, I bind something in jquery -

```
$("p").bind("click", {foo: "bar"}, handler)
```

Could I rightclick on handler, then choose an option to stub out a function?

Doesn't have to be a right click, a keyboard shortcut would be even better.

I've added textmate to the tags, as Sublime is compatible with text mate plugins.

Comment: Although it's not too tricky to type out an anonymous function, this would be very handy. +1

Answer (score 7):

You just need to type `f` and then press `tab`
Bonus: typing `fun` and then pressing `tab` will give you a named function

Comment: Not precisely what the OP wanted, imo, but pretty daggum helpful in general.  ;^)

Answer (score 0):

This would be very easy to do with a plugin.  Sublime Text has a very extendable API and uses python for its plugins.  You will get a much better response if you post this on sublime text's forum: sublimetext.com/forum/

Many people are willing to help you there and will probably make the plugin for you in a matter of minutes.